# Moving from specialized knowledge role in India to a functional manager in US -- L1B or L1A

Tags: indian-citizens, l1-visa

If a software developer in India (specialized knowledge employee) moves to a program manager role in US (which ends up being a functional manager along-with a specialized knowledge employee in many cases), usually, will the person be granted a L1A or L1B visa?

Answer (score 1):

L1A is for international execs, L1B is for special knowledge. For L1A you'll need to show that you manage work of other people and budgets across borders. Generally, L1A requires prior management position before transfer (at least all the L1A's I've met had to show that). If you're individual contributor or a junior manager (i.e.: team-lead level), even as a program manager you'll probably get L1b.